# Qt Sqlite Query does not work

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to run this query to SQlite database but its not executing from Qt
but when I go to navicat and execute the same query it works very fine with no problems

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT token FROM tokens WHERE SOUNDEX(token) = SOUNDEX('search')");

if(!query.exec()){
    QMessageBox::information(this,"Error","query won't execute"); //will be displayed
}

QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
    int cols = rec.count(); //0
```

where if I executed any other select stamement it works very fine

Comment: Use the lastError method of QSqlQuery to guess what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `SOUNDEX` algorithm is disabled by default and you have to use the compiler flag `-DSQLITE_SOUNDEX=1` when building [`sqlite`](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#soundex).

So you have to build the `sqlite` driver with this flag on, and then build the plugin by linking it to your [`sqlite` build](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt4-preview-feedback/2005-05/thread01021-0.html).